Async function stops in middle
Why this code stops in middle?


async function main () {
    await new Promise(() => {
        console.log('Hello world')
    })
    console.log('debug1')
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    console.log('finish')
}

main()



This code only print "Hello world", but not "debug1" or "finish", why?

A promise takes a function with at least one, but ideally two arguments: a resolve callback function as first argument, and a reject callback function as second argument. You've given your first promise neither and so it will never complete.

You didn't resolve the first promise, so the code got stuck waiting for the promise to resolve. To fix it, resolve the promise like this:


async function main () {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log('Hello world');
        resolve();
    })
    console.log('debug1')
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    console.log('finish')
}

main()




But do i return some resolve is second Promise? @AndrewParks

@Xmajkl yes, your second Promise is approximately equivalent to the code: await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000));, meaning that resolve is called after 1 second.
